# Set default size for BLOB in Spring SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible to set the Blob size under Hibernate properties in the sessionFactory bean?

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can use `@Column ( length = somefix number )` with the `@Lob` fields inside your `@Entity` class.

Comment: or is it possible to do it for just tests? im using an embedded database which is setting the blob size as 255 (sql contains blob (255), ...) when it needs to be much bigger